# $jQuery Easy Slider Numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

Estou utilizando o Jquery easySlider1.7.js, e tenho uma duvida sobre a propriedade 'numeric'.

Ao utilizar esta propriedade, o plugin adicionar a baixo das imagens um link para cada slide, só que ao selecionar um deles, a rolagem automática é desabilitada.

É possível manter a rolagem automática, mesmo clicando em um dos links ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Link: http://www.optimist.org/easyslider/02a.html

Obs: Ao selecionar qualquer slide, a rolagem automática é desabilitada.

Comment: Cara, eu não entendi direito sua pergunta. Você quer desabilitar a rolagem automática? Deixa o `auto` em `false`.

Comment: Não, quero saber se é possível que a rolagem automática continue mesmo se o usuário clicar em um índice do numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Faça as seguintes modificações no arquivo easySlider1.7.js:

1. **Linha 158** substitua "t = dir" por "**t = parseInt(dir)**"
2. **Linha 195** substitua "if(options.auto && dir=="next" && !clicked)" por "**if(options.numeric)**"

Fiz o teste e funcionou.

Referências:

- [stackoverflow.com/questions/4842375/jquery-easy-slider-plugin-restarting-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842375/jquery-easy-slider-plugin-restarting-animation)